# Is there any reason that the apache webroot /var/www/html is set as root-owned?

Tags: apache, web-services, webserver, lamp, digital-ocean

I just launched a LAMP dropplet from Digital Ocean and am starting coding. When trying to create a new directory inside the web root it says

> mkdir: cannot create directory ‘blog’: Permission denied

I can fix this by running `chown -R user /var/www/html` but I'm wondering if this will break things or if there's a better way of doing this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a variety of options on permissions, but essentially `www-data` needs read (and probably execute) permission.

I like to redefine the [`DocumentRoot`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html) in my [`VirtualHost`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html) definitions to use something other than `/var/www/html`, anyway.

For example, you could use `/srv/www/sitename`, and then assign permissions `myuser:www-data` to it.

There are also numerous threads on the DigitalOcean forums (and around the internet) about permissions schemes for web files. (e.g. [Proper Permissions for Web Server Directory](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/proper-permissions-for-web-server-s-directory).)

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the answer. I'll definitely change the document root and read through that forum page.